java.lang.IllegalStateException: Batch statement cannot contain more than 65535 statements in scyalla db using java driver
I am new in ScyllaDB. For my project I want to update one column(pin table) from another table (client). So at first I select col1, customerID from client table, then for each row: add row into batch statement. If batchStatement is reached at 100 statement, then executed and new builder is instantiated.
I didn't find out why I am getting this error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Batch statement cannot contain more than 65535 statements.
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.cql.BatchStatementBuilder.addStatement(BatchStatementBuilder.java:84)



public void updateBillingPassword(CassandraConnector connector) {
        try {
         
            Select select = selectFrom(connector.getDatabase(), "Client")
                    .column("col1")
                    .column("customerid");
            SimpleStatement selectStatement = select.build().setTimeout(Duration.ofHours(5));
            ResultSet resultSet = connector.execute(selectStatement);

            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connector.getSession().prepare(
                "Update Pin set pinCol=:value where pinNO=:clcustomerid"
            );

            BatchStatementBuilder batchStatementBuilder = BatchStatement.builder(DefaultBatchType.UNLOGGED);
            int count=0, batchSize = 100;
            Iterator<Row> iterator = resultSet.iterator();
            while(iterator.hasNext()){
                Row row = iterator.next();
                String col1 = row.getString("col1");
                String clcustomerid = row.getString("customerid");
                if (col1 != null && clcustomerid!=null) {
                    count++;
                    
                    batchStatementBuilder = batchStatementBuilder.addStatement(preparedStatement.bind(col1, clcustomerid));

                    try{
                        if(count%batchSize==0 || !iterator.hasNext()){
                            LOGGER.info("Executing batch statement...");
                            System.out.println("Executing batch statement...");
                            connector.getSession().execute(batchStatementBuilder.build());
                            LOGGER.info("Executed batch statement.");
                            System.out.println("Executed batch statement.");
                            batchStatementBuilder = BatchStatement.builder(DefaultBatchType.UNLOGGED);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e){
                        LOGGER.error("",e);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle exceptions
            LOGGER.error("",e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

